# Cannot return current user object in Meteor / MongoDB

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am working on an admin page where I need to look up the object properties of a user whose user profile page I am on. I am trying to query the user's object and attributes but I keep getting 'undefined' in the console. I want to click a button and have the console spit out the object & its properties. It's worth noting that I am able to print out the user's _id field, but nothing else.

Here's my click event:

```
'click .confirmUser': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentUserId = this._id;
    var currUser = Meteor.users.find(currentUserId)
    console.log('current user id is ' + currentUserId);
    console.log(currUser.profile);
    console.log(currUser.id);
    console.log(currUser._id);
```

The output I get is:

```
current user id is JY2hydg9NWwHwpoNS
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Does anyone know what's going on? I used the exact same type of coding in my adminController to check the admin's isAdmin flag, which worked, so I'm not sure why this isn't working... Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try changin find to findOne or use .fetch() and do a console.log(currUser[0].username) since .fetch returns an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing that query to

```
Meteor.users.findOne(currentUserId)
```

You get undefined because you are using `.find()` wich retruns the collections instance and not the objects use `fetch()` instead.

And do the console.log like this

```
console.log(currUser[0].username)
```

to check this if you print the `Meteor.users.find(currentUserId)`, you will get something like `Local.Collection({object:null},etc)`